# Cast exception issue in map with values of type Object

Tags: java, string, dictionary, boolean, classcastexception

Follow the code block.

```
Map<String, Object> personDetailMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
personDetailMap.put("name", "isuru");
personDetailMap.put("is-male", true);
(String)personDetailMap.get("is-male");
```

Final statement causes an exception: ClassCastException cannot cast Boolean to String
also note that value I'm trying to read is put as of primitive type boolean

My question is personDetailMap will return a object of Class Object then why its giving a cast exception of Boolean to String.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: "Heterogeneous" maps like this, even if you can make them technically work, are often considered code smells that you're better off avoiding.

Answer (score 3):

`personDetailMap.put("is-male", true);` stores a `Boolean` by boxing the primitive `boolean` into an object.
`personDetailMap.get("is-male");` returns that same `Boolean`.

Then you try to cast the `Boolean` to a `String` although those 2 classes have no relationship. The cast fails and you get that exception.

The statement `(String) anObject;` can only work if `anObject` **is** a String (String being final, there aren't any sub classes).

If you actually want to convert the boolean into a string, you can use the following method:

```
String boolStr = personDetailMap.get("is-male").toString(); // boolStr = "true"
```

Comment: Or you can use String boolStr = personDetailMap.get("is-male")+"";